# Execute a function when the button clicked

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

Currently, I used laravel and AngularJS on my web page. and I want to execute a function that can show and hide a form when the button clicked. after I wrote that code, the form has successfully shown up, but can't be hide.

i wrote the function code on master.blade.php page :

```
var masterCtrl = angular.module('olshopApp', ['ngRoute']);

        masterCtrl.controller('createController', function($scope){
            $scope.isVisible = 'true';
            $scope.ShowHide = function(){
                $scope.IsVisible  = !$scope.IsVisible;
            };

        });
```

and these the code on product.blade.php page

```
<div class="form-actions" ng-controller="createController">
        <button class="btn btn-primary icon-pencil bigger-110" type="button" ng-click="ShowHide()">
            Add New
        </button>
    </div>

    <div create-product ng-hide="isVisible"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. The scope of your controller is just limited to the first `div` which is wrong. Put the `ng-controller="createController"` to a parent `div` as given.
2. The variable name (case) is wrong in this line `$scope.IsVisible  = !$scope.IsVisible;`. It should be `$scope.isVisible  = !$scope.isVisible;`
3. You have used a String value instead of Boolean value in the `$scope.isVisible` variable. Just change that line to: `$scope.isVisible = true;` (This is an improvement not the problem)

See a working example below:

```js
var masterCtrl = angular.module('olshopApp', []);

masterCtrl.controller('createController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isVisible = true;
  
  $scope.ShowHide = function() {
    console.log($scope.isVisible)
    $scope.isVisible = !$scope.isVisible;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="olshopApp" ng-controller="createController">
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-primary icon-pencil bigger-110" type="button" ng-click="ShowHide()">
      Add New
    </button>
  </div>

  <div create-product ng-hide="isVisible">Hello. Create Product form will be displayed here. I'll be shown or hidden on button click.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that line `$scope.IsVisible  = !$scope.IsVisible;` and instead write
 `$scope.isVisible  = !$scope.isVisible;`